# testing hashCode for Strings

Tags: java, string, hashcode

I am writing the code shown below:

```
String s1=new String("hi");
System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
String s2=new String("hi");
System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
String s3=s1.intern();
String s4=s2.intern();
System.out.println(s3.hashCode());
System.out.println(s4.hashCode());
```

When I run the code the same hashcode is printing for all variables:

```
3329
3329
3329
3329
```

Is it correct output for the above code?

Comment: Is there a reason to *doubt* the output of the JVM? What did you expect?.

Comment: You might also try `"iJ".hashCode()` to confirm that different strings can also produce that same hash.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's the correct output. [The `hashCode` of `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) is based on the *content* of the String (in a very specific way, documented in the documentation linked to above).

And since `s1`, `s2`, `s3` and `s4` all have the same content ("hi"), they all return the same hashCode.

That's actually *required* since object to which `a.equals(b)` return `true` are *required* to return the same values for `a.hashCode()` and `b.hashCode()`.

Note that the opposite (i.e. "objects with the same hashcode have to be equal") is *not true* and can't even be done in general (simply consider that there are a lot more possible `String` values than there are `int` values, see [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).

Answer (score 3):

All your strings are `equal` so it makes sense that they have the same hashcode. That is part of the contract for hashcode defined [in Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Answer (score 1):

someone correct me if i'm wrong, but i think yes, it is the correct output as you get the hascode for the string "hi" and not for the string-objects. and that's exactly what the hashcode-method should do.